# Having trouble with Laravel Breadcrumbs

Tags: laravel, breadcrumbs

I'm using davejamesmiller's Breadcrumbs package and I have some trouble with getting post category in post view. I want my breadcrumbs to be like this :

```
Home > Category > Post
```

I defined breadcrumbs like this:

```
// Home
    Breadcrumbs::for('home', function ($trail) {
    $trail->push('Home', route('home'));
});

// Home > [Category]
Breadcrumbs::for('category', function ($trail, $category) {
    $trail->parent('home');
    $trail->push($category->title, route('category', $category->slug));
});

// Home > [Category] > [Post]
Breadcrumbs::for('post', function ($trail, $post) {
    $trail->parent('category', $post->category);
    $trail->push($post->title, route('post', $post->slug));
});
```

And called this code in the post view template to output breadcrumbs:

```
{{ Breadcrumbs::render( 'course', $course, $category ) }}
```

But getting this error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$category
```

And this refers to this line of defined breadcrumb:

```
$trail->parent('category', $post->category);
```

My posts table does'nt have category column and I don't know what should I pass as the second parameter of parent method! Should I pass post's category row which is in other table to my post view? What should I pass as second parameter?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$category->title` again? Like `$trail->parent('category', $category->title);`?

Comment: getting Undefined variable $category error with $category->title while i'm passing the post's category row to view

Comment: Ah I see it; `function($category)`; thought it was available outside of that scope. So  am I correct in assuming that `Post` to `Category` is a Many-to-Many?

Comment: each post in posts table can have one category in categories table. in fact every categry can have many posts.

Comment: That's odd; `$post->category` should be available, as long as you defined `public function category(){ ... }` on `Post`; Also, `Post` shouldn't be a `stdClass`, should be a `Post` model. Might need to do some `dd()`s in your code; see what `$post` is and what it contains. Also, when you try to access a property of a `Model`, like `$model->notAProperty`, you should get `null`, not an `stdClass` error.

Comment: $post->category refers to property or column of posts table row which I don't know what type of data it should be! title? slug? url? or what

Comment: I also output breadcrumbs in view with `{{ Breadcrumbs::render( 'post', $post ) }}`. $post is passed posts row table to view.

Comment: How is your `$post` defined? Using `DB::table()`? Or do you have `Post` Eloquent model defined and queried (like `Post::where()->first()`, etc.)

Comment: Using DB::table() joined with other table.

Comment: There you go. So you either joined it wrong to not have the column `categories.title` available, or you should define a Model, use `Relationship` logic to Category to Post, and then use `$post->category->title`. Right now, `$post` is a `stdClass` that doesn't have a column `category` available.

Comment: Thanks man. I'll try more.

Comment: Happy to help. Just update your question if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by passing `$category` variable to the breadcrumb that I was defined. like this:

```
Breadcrumbs::for('post', function ($trail, $post, $category) {
    $trail->parent('category', $category);
    $trail->push($post->title, route('post', $post->slug));
});
```

then in my view I changed the output code to:

```
{{ Breadcrumbs::render( 'post', $post, $category ) }}
```

I also passed the post's category table row to view from controller.